# How to Add a Shortcut Icon on mobile (Install to homescreen)

Tags: android, html

I've already searched about this, but I didn't work.

What I want is when a user try to "Install to homescreen" on my page, on mobile, it installs a shortcut with **MY ICON**. But the icon, doesn't appears.

I've put this on my *Login/Default.ctp*:

```
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://www.iconj.com/ico/t/3/t3c14scn7l.ico"/>
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="http://localhost/SysApp/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/SysApp/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/SysApp/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/SysApp/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/SysApp/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
            <link rel="manifest" href="http://localhost/SysApp/manifest.json">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.iconj.com/ico/t/3/t3c14scn7l.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/SysApp/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.iconj.com/ico/n/1/n1f2a7gyhf.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            <link rel="icon" href="http://localhost/SysApp/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
            <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
            <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://localhost/SysApp/mstile-144x144.png">
            <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
            <meta content="icon-uri=http://www.iconj.com/ico/t/3/t3c14scn7l.ico; window=self" name="msapplication-task">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
            <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
            <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://localhost/SysApp/android-chrome-192x192.png">
```

And when I tried to "Install to homescreen" on Chrome for Android, it didn't work (icon doesn't appears), the shortcut is on my homescreen, but without a icon.

Please help.